# copy a hidden sheet with a multiple formulas to create a multiple new sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I created a procedure which does this:

- copy one hidden sheet with that contains a table with a significant number of formulas ( table size is 100 R x 11 C , about 8 column includes formulas (some of them are quite advanced)) and create new identical sheet but with a different name indicated by the user in different section of the model (essentially in another table).

I am using an array to pick up the sheets names (strings are appended to array from a named range 'rng_Target' which user of the tool provides) to be created , that are provided by the user (at the moment maximum 10 new sheets can be created.

My problem is the time it takes for this procedure to create those sheets - it takes really long time - up to 5min.

Is there anything obviously wrong with my code please? File: Create Copy of sheet-code 1

I have to say , the previous version of the code used (which does not involve arrays) , seemed to be working much faster (for some of the users) ; which i don't understand - see File: Create Copy of sheet-code 2

How can i change my existing code to run it faster?

Code 1

```
Option Explicit
Dim myArray() As Variant
Dim FSinput As String
Dim wrksh As Worksheet
Dim MasterWB As Workbook
Dim MainTool As String
Dim Path_to_save As String




Sub ConvertInput() ' wrzuc input od uzytkownika z named range w tablice
    Dim i As Integer
    
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.StatusBar = False
  
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  
    On Error Resume Next

  If wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden Or wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
  wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetVisible
  End If
  

    myArray = Range("rng_Target").Value
    
    For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    
            If IsEmpty(myArray(i, 1)) = False Then   'sprawdz czy element of myarray jest pusty czy jest tam jakas wartosc (string)
                
                  wsToDuplicate.Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
                  With ActiveSheet
                  .Name = myArray(i, 1)
                  End With
                  
            End If
                 '================Ten fragment tylko do testu czy array dziala================
                   'MsgBox myArray(i, 1)
                   'Debug.Print myArray(i, 1)
                 '============================================================================
    Next i
    
    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Erase myArray() ' wyczysc array
    '^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   
 If wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetVisible Or wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
 wsToDuplicate.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
 End If
    
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.StatusBar = True

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub CopySheetAndRenameByCell2()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, c As Range
  Set sh1 = Sheets("Lead - TO DELETE")
  Set sh2 = Sheets("Lead list & MAT")
        For Each c In sh2.Range("G4:G13")
            sh1.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
            ActiveSheet.Name = c.Value
        Next
       Sheets("Lead - TO DELETE").Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Please avoid using `On Error Resume Next` unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored. What the range of `rng_Target`?

Comment: Hello and thanks for responding. rng_Target is a named range in excel - essentially 1 column of 10 rows where the user inputs some financial names used to create individual tabs.

Comment: Comment out `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and run code again. If the processing time is significantly reduced, it indicates that the bottleneck lies in the calculation of formulas.

Comment: @taller, what a beautiful creation you are. You cannot imagine my face expression when I did what you suggested and run the tool again. IT WORKS  AND IT WORKS SUPER FAST! Much faster than the original code. YOU ARE A GENIUS!

Comment: @taller - don't seem to be having option to accept your answer as BEST ONE and FINAL...

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` and run code again. If the processing time is significantly reduced, it indicates that the bottleneck lies in the calculation of formulas. That is, your code works well.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.Calculation property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.calculation?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133084)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [XlCalculation enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcalculation?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)